# Read SQL query from file in Minitab

Tags: odbc, minitab, minitab-16

I know how to run a SQL query in minitab using :

```
ODBC;
  Connect "Driver={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};Database=...";
  SQLString "SELECT * FROM Table".
```

However, this is very constraining since the length of the command line is limited in Minitab... Instead of manually shorten each line to right length, would it be possible to directly read the query from a text file?

Answer (score -1):

You can have Minitab read text command files from an Exec file. You can create an Exec file using any text editor, and saving the file with the .mtb extension.